# Matching anything but a letter - regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

How to match anything BUT a letter? i thought `[^a-z]+` will do but not really.

I have this string to search in:

```
"price":"7.99","opt":{"1":[1.01,1.02]},"mixedId":0,"price":"8.99","opt":{"3":[1.03],"4":[1.04,1.05]}
```

I want to get these values `8.99` and `1.04,1.05` but it can't match `7.99`

I did like this:

```
'"price":"(.+?)","opt":\{"[^a-z]*"4":\[(.+?)]'
```

but it finds nothing. Need some support :)

Comment: you mean match everything but a digit? http://regex101.com/r/nJ5qP8 ?

Comment: Your data almost looks like JSON (apart from the double `"price"` key and the missing outer `{ .. }` braces. Why search through that as a string? Why not instead interpret that as JSON?

Comment: Thanks for answers! @kaᵠ this site looks great, thanks a million. @Martijn, as far as I know this is not JSON but a simply text/html. @Rob ahh, my bad I want to get `1.04,1.05` not `1.01,1.02` thanks for pinting that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fixed RegEx should look something like this:

`"price":"([\d\.]+?)","opt":\{"[^a-z]*"4":\[(.+?)\]`

Live demo here: http://regex101.com/r/iU3oT7

Answer (score 3):

The following regex will match what you want (digits and periods), including '1':

```
[\d\.]+
```

If you only want to match digits that contain a period and two decimals you can use the following pattern:

```
\d+\.\d{2}
```

Comment: But what about `:`? I still need to match those.

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

def handle_duplicates(pairs):    
    d = {}
    for k, v in pairs:
        if k in d:
           d[k].append(v)
        else:
           d.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)
    return d

s = '{"price":"7.99","opt":{"1":[1.01,1.02]},"mixedId":0,"price":"8.99","opt":{"3":[1.03],"4":[1.04,1.05]}}'

d = json.loads(s, object_pairs_hook=handle_duplicates)
print d
```

out:

```
{u'mixedId': [0],
 u'opt': [{u'1': [[1.01, 1.02]]}, {u'3': [[1.03]], u'4': [[1.04, 1.05]]}],
 u'price': [u'7.99', u'8.99']}
```

As you now have a dict, you can get the price list like `d['price']`

Comment: Thank you v much for this detailed explanation. I'll have to dive into json as this looks pretty handy. THX!

Answer (score 0):

To match everything that is not a letter (as in the original question), use this character class, which is a modification of `\w` from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html):

```
[^a-zA-Z]
```

Reading from the follow-up comments, it sounds like you are more interested in group 1 of this character class similar to @Mauritz Hansen:

```
'\[([\d\.,]*)\]
```

I'm confused what you mean by "I need to match : as well." This Python code finds the prices `1.01` to `1.05`:

```
import re

txt = '"price":"7.99","opt":{"1":[1.01,1.02]},"mixedId":0,"price":"8.99","opt":{"3":[1.03],"4":[1.04,1.05]}'

pattern = '\\[([\d\\.,]*)\\]'

for m in re.finditer(pattern2, txt):
    print m.group(1)
```

Output:

```
1.01,1.02
1.03
1.04,1.05
```