# Python regex match all characters except tab

Tags: python, regex

How can I match any character except horizontal tabulator? The group I would like to capture are characters preceded by ':' and followed by '\t'.

```
regex = re.compile(r'^p:([^\t]*)\t')
line = 'p:452c942b93\tperson\tSimon Sturridge'
if regex.match(line):
    print 'MATCH'
```

Thanks.

EDIT: I would like to match a string of this format 'p:'+'random numbers and letters'+'\t'
and capture the random numbers and letters following ':' and preceding '\t'. I apologize for a the lack of conciseness.

Comment: Can you provide sample input and expected output, and what output you are actually getting?

Comment: Related: [regular expression matching everything except a given regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781554/regular-expression-matching-everything-except-a-given-regular-expression) [Matching anything but a letter - regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348457/matching-anything-but-a-letter-regex)

Comment: The code you provide *is* matching for me on both 2.7 and 3.4.

Comment: I checked the snippet and it works alone, the problem is somewhere else probably. Again, apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you described, I would say:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^p:(\w*)\t')
foo = re.match(pattern, line)
if foo:
  print 'MATCH'
```

Test:

```
>>> foo.groups()
('452c942b93',)
>>>foo.group(1)
'452c942b93'
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to match specifically all characters except \t? Is [^\t] correct for this purpose?

Comment: I believe this is what you need, right?